# Error: assignment of Read-only location C language

Tags: c, static-linking

Just so you know, I am VERY new to programming. I am in a way trying to teach myself. so here's just a little something I've been working on. I'm trying to get it to link, to where if my scanf(%c) is equal to D, it asks how much to deposit, etc. for some reason I can't get past this error..... any clue what I'm doing wrong?

```
main(void)
{
    char Deposit,Withdrawl,Exit,amount,balance;
    char D,W,E;
    balance=100;
    Deposit=D;
    Withdrawl=W;
    Exit=E;
    printf("please enter the type of action: D-eposit, W-ithdrawl, or E-xit:\n");
    scanf("%c");

    if("%c"=D)
    {
        printf("Please enter the amount to deposit:/n");
        scanf("%f");
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to enable warnings in your compiler. You have multiple uses of variables before they are initialized, which renders the entire program pretty much undefined behavior.

Comment: You should buy a book about c first. Do very simple stuff and then progress. Propably `scanf` is to advanced for you now. My 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
scanf("%c");
if("%c"=D)
```

To:

```
char x;
scanf("%c",&x);
if (x == 'D')
```

(to begin with)...

In addition, the following piece of code is useless (not sure what plans you had in mind for it):

```
Deposit=D;
Withdrawl=W;
Exit=E;
```

And finally, the second call to `scanf` should also take the address of a `float` variable.